# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, you program the year. I am working on a tester to measure a measurement, e.g.: charging current, battery voltage.
I encountered a problem adding a barcode scanner before I had the buttons from the excel I downloaded the data correctly. When I added a scanner `("self")`: here a problem such as:
`'NoneType'` object has no attribute '**getitem**
And this applies to data retrieval from the excel, normally loads luminaires, and `variable_RW`.
I give the code below:

```
global dupa_3
dupa_3 = 0
global dupa_2
dupa_2 = 0
global dupa
dupa = 0
def skaner (self):
    global oprawy
    global zmienna_RW
    global przychod_wewnetrzny
    global szt
    global zmienna_KTM
    global KTM_P
    zmienna_RW = przychod_wewnetrzny
    if zmienna_RW == (""):
        info_2()
        dupa_2 = 1
    else:
        dupa_2 = 2
    if dupa_2 == 2:
        zmienna_RW = przychod_wewnetrzny
        #label_8 = Label(okno,background ="#565a58",fg="#dedede", text= (zmienna_RW))
        #label_8.grid(row=2, column=4)

    oprawy = szt
    if oprawy == (""):
        info_2()
        dupa_3 = 1
    else:
        dupa_3 = 2

    if dupa_3 == 2:
        oprawy = int (szt)
        global oprawy_1
        oprawy_1 = oprawy

    zmienna_KTM = KTM_P
    if zmienna_KTM == (""):
        info_2()
        dupa=1
    else:
        dupa=2

    if dupa == 2:
        zmienna_KTM = KTM_P
        #string_to_display =  zmienna_KTM   #"KTM " +
        #label_2 = Label(okno,background ="#565a58", fg="#dedede")
        #label_2["text"]=string_to_display
        #label_2.grid(row=0, column=4)
        workbook = load_workbook ( "//Poczernin/test room/Parametry/raport.xlsx" )
        sheet = workbook. get_sheet_by_name(zmienna_KTM)
        #global moc_min
        #moc_min = sheet ['A1'].value
        global moc_max
        moc_max = sheet ['B1'].value
        global prad_minimalny
        prad_minimalny = sheet ['A2'].value
        global prad_maksymalny
        prad_maksymalny = sheet ['B2'].value
        global prad_rozladowania_min
        prad_rozladowania_min = sheet ['A3'].value
        global prad_rozladowania_max
        prad_rozladowania_max = sheet ['B3'].value
        global napiecie_min
        napiecie_min = sheet ['A4'].value
        global napiecie_max
        napiecie_max = sheet ['B4'].value
        global nazwa
        nazwa = sheet ['C1'].value

        label18 = Label (okno,height=1, width=10,background ="#565a58" , fg="#dedede",font="none 20", text = (moc_min))
        label19 = Label (okno,height=1, width=10,background ="#565a58" , fg="#dedede",font="none 20", text = (moc_max))
        label11 = Label (okno,height=1, width=10,background ="#565a58" , fg="#dedede",font="none 20", text = (prad_minimalny))
        label12 = Label (okno,height=1, width=10,background ="#565a58" , fg="#dedede",font="none 20", text = (prad_rozladowania_min))
        label13 = Label (okno,height=1, width=10,background ="#565a58" , fg="#dedede",font="none 20", text = (napiecie_min))
        label14 = Label (okno,height=1, width=10,background ="#565a58" , fg="#dedede",font="none 20", text = (prad_maksymalny))
        label15 = Label (okno,height=1, width=10,background ="#565a58" , fg="#dedede",font="none 20", text = (prad_rozladowania_max))
        label16 = Label (okno,height=1, width=10,background ="#565a58" , fg="#dedede",font="none 20", text = (napiecie_max))
        label21 = Label (okno,background ="#565a58" , fg="#dedede",font="none 10", text = (nazwa))


        label18.grid(row=4, column = 2)
        label19.grid(row=4, column = 4)
        label11.grid(row=5, column = 2)
        label12.grid(row=6, column = 2)
        label13.grid(row=7, column = 2)
        label14.grid(row=5, column = 4)
        label15.grid(row=6, column = 4)
        label16.grid(row=7, column = 4)
        label21.grid(row=0, column = 5)

dane = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Przychod wewnetrzny", "Prosze wprowadz dane")
output = (dane)
global przychod_wewnetrzny
przychod_wewnetrzny = output[10:19]
global KTM_P
KTM_P = output[20:32]
global szt
szt = output[33:35]

okno.bind("<Return>",skaner)
```

> I got this message with idle: Exception in Tkinter callback
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in call return  
>   self.func(*args)  
> File "C:/tester produkcyjny/app v2.0.py", line 436, in skaner  
>   moc_min = sheet ['A1'].value 
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getitem
> ```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can you edit your question to include full traceback?

Comment: I noticed your variable names are in a different language other than English. What is the language?

Comment: I come from Poland. I'm Polish

Comment: Please, I added this in the main thread, and removed the comment.

Comment: The error basically means that you are trying to extract information from something that does not exist. Could be a spelling mistake or anything else really. It is esential to us to know where exactly the error occurs

Comment: `__getitem__` is called when using the `[]` operator.  The only places I see this happen are with the variables `sheet` and `output`, so double check to make sure those aren't `None`.

Comment: I do not know if I understand correctly, the point is that I want to download data from the exel but I do not have them there?

Comment: Add `print(zmienna_KTM)` bevor this line `sheet = workbook. get_sheet_by_name(zmienna_KTM)` and check if a `Sheet` by this name exists.

Comment: I added and I'm surprised, KTM correctly appeared properly and the application loaded all the data :) Just why did it happen?

Comment: But the second time, KTM_P and a mistake appeared as before

Comment: A few lines above, you have `zmienna_KTM = KTM_P`. Check your **whole** script **where** `KTM_P` **get set** or **unset**.

Comment: I also added print (sheet) and idle actually returned None

Comment: probably the problem solved in the exel I have the name of the sheet as inlmdu 39942, and when the scanner or program reads it as uppercase then throws the error and when read small then the application works correctly, you had a good idea with print (zmienna_KTM) thanks to this I saw tylko jak zapobiec temu żeby nie czytał raz duże a raz małe litery

Comment: Use `zmienna_KTM = KTM_P.lower()`. Beside this `workbook. get_sheet_by_name(...` is deprecated use `workbook[zmienna_KTM]` instead. This will raise `KeyError("Worksheet {0} does not exist."`, which was the culprit.

Comment: Ok, so I will. Thank you for your help and time.
greetings